# How to use させる in a series of verbs

Tags: grammar, causation

When させる is used to say "let A do B", for example,

> Let the dog move forward.
>
> 犬を前に進ませる。

What if I add more verbs there? Say

> Let the dog move forward, sit in front of the wall and take a bite of the bone.

here is my attempt

> 犬を前に進ませて、壁の前に座らせて、骨を食べさせる。

Is this correct, or are there any other ways to express it more naturally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentence looks just fine. When you want to avoid saying させる many times (esp. if there are even more actions), other options include:

- 犬に、前に進んで壁の前に座って骨を食べるようにさせる。
- 前に進み壁の前に座り骨を食べるよう、{犬に命令する/犬を動かす/犬を誘導する/etc}。

Comment: @aguijonazo はい。そのほうが単調にならないので良い気がなんとなくするのですが、だめですかね。

Comment: @aguijonazo それもそうですね、ということで修正しました